# ElasticSearch/Kibana: Time zone change from UTC to eastern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

How do I change the time zone on the Kibana 'Discover' tab? Currently, it is displaying UTC time zone and want all my date fields to show up as 'Eastern time zone'. The way I am currently doing is by going to Kibana then click `'Management' tab -> 'Advanced Settings' -> Name: dateFormat:tz to Value: 'America/New_York' from the drop down and save it`. However, when I go to my 'Discover' tab, the date has not been changed to 'America/New_York'. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other settings I should look for? Do I need to set this up during Indexing? Thanks!

Comment: you are doing it right please verify if it is properly updated or not.

Comment: about indexing the time you will set there will be converted using settings you specify in settings of kibana.

you can check that in ES time is always same you index documents with but in kibana, this thing is showing some bad behavior.